# Python3 ORM, превращающий camelCase в snake_case

Tags: python, python-3.x

Мне от стороннего сервиса приходит json со строковыми полями в camelCase 
я могу этот json превраттить в dict и, используя dataclasses замапить ответ на python-object, однако тогда мне придется пользоваться camelCase'ом в своем python коде.

Можно ли сделать так, чтобы как в springBoot - вешаешь аннотацию на поле, обозначающую название поля, данные из которого надо замапить в помеченное аннотацией?

Например, так это выглядит в котлине и спринге:
@JsonProperty("auto_renew_product_id ") val renewProductId: String?

есть ли что-то такое.в python3 ?

Comment: Задача привести ключи в JSON из `camelCase` в `snake_case`, правильно? Можете привести пример того json'а?

Comment: могу, но в целом вы праивльно поняли формат

Answer (score 1):

Насчет сериализации в поля с указанием имени ключа JSON не смогу подсказать, но пример приведения строки в `snake_case` и создание нового словаря с ключами с `snake_case`, пожалуйста.

Пример:

```
import re

def camel_to_snake(name: str) -> str:
    return re.sub(r'(?!^)(?=[A-Z])', '_', name).lower()

def deep_camel_to_snake(d: dict) -> dict:
    new_dict = dict()
    for k, v in d.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            v = deep_camel_to_snake(v)
        elif isinstance(v, list):
            v = [deep_camel_to_snake(x) if isinstance(x, dict) else x for x in v]
        new_dict[camel_to_snake(k)] = v
    return new_dict

data = {
    'dataObj': {
        'itemsObj': [
            {
                'UserName': 'xxx',
                'UserAge': 0,
            }
        ],
        'renewProductId': 1,
        'UserId': 1
    }
}
data = deep_camel_to_snake(data)
print(data)
# {'data_obj': {'items_obj': [{'user_name': 'xxx', 'user_age': 0}], 'renew_product_id': 1, 'user_id': 1}}
```

Comment: хочется отметить это дело как тревога, сорри, я мог бы, но не хочу дергать эти два метода на каждый реквест, у меня json ответы слишком здоровые

Comment: @Stvlpotapov, пусть этот ответ будет как запасной план :)

Comment: договорились, посмотрим, будут ли еще ответы)

Comment: `(?<!^)` - зачем так мудрить-то? Это ж то же самое, что `(?!^)`.

Comment: @Qwertiy, спасибо, подправил